# how can I import "Dense3D" and use it in code?

Tags: python, pytorch, torch

I tried to run a code from git but i found a problem with importing Dense3D.
here the part of code witch relate to the problem:

here the part of code that relate to the problem:

```py
   import torch
   from torch.models import Dense3D
   import torch.nn as nn
   #some lines deleted
   print("Loading options...")
   with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as optionsFile:
       options = toml.loads(optionsFile.read())
   #Create the model.
   model = Dense3D(options)
```

it make error that *"can't import Dense3D"* or something like this in another tries with some changes.

and i used colab .

Comment: There should be no module `torch.models` in pytorch.  For models, the module is [`torchvision.models`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torchvision/models.html) and even it does not have any Dense3D class. However there is DenseNet. Can you share  link to the  code you are using?

Comment: the link is "https://github.com/Fengdalu/Lipreading-DenseNet3D" in main.py

Comment: I guess there is a difference in your code and their code.  they have `from models.Dense3D import Dense3D` which means `models` as a local module belonging to their project, while you are trying to import it from torch by calling `torch.models`.

Comment: yes that's right,but it didn't worked in that way too,
so it mean's we need a local model?

Comment: right,i missed model part.